# C++ divide numbers using transform (bind)

Tags: c++, transform, bind, divide

How can I use transform to divide a list of numbers by 2? I thought this code would do it, but it only divides the number 1 with 2 for the whole list, so I must have missunderstod this completely. Can someone help me, please? :)

```
list<T> v(5, 1);
list<T> d;
d.resize(v.size());

transform(v.begin(), v.end(), d.begin(), bind(divides<T>(), placeholders::_1, 2));
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
for (list<T>::iterator i = d.begin(); i != d.end(); i++){
    std::cout << *i << endl;
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: Well you initialize the list `v` with five elements, all being the integer `1`. So what else did you expect?

Comment: Okay, my mistake, I guess i thought that placeholders::_1 was some kind of a constant (I read somewhere that _1 was insted of x, but I must have missunderstod that). So, what can I do to change that, I guess I need something else than placehoders then?!

Comment: `placeholders::_1` is a placeholder for the first argument, you're using it correctly. I'm talking about the construction of the variable `v` as a list of five `1`. If you print out the list `v` you will see it being all `1`. So of course the result will be that all divisions will be `1 / 2`. The problem isn't how you use `transform` or `bind` or anything like that, it is the source data that is the problem.

Comment: Haha, sorry, im to tired. I dont know why I did that. Of course that doesnt work. Sometimes Im just so stupid! Thanks! <3

Answer (score 1):

1. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
2. There's is no reason to use list over vector in your example.
3. Unless you're bound to C++98 you can do `transform(...,..., [](T& val) { val /= 2; });`
4. `std::cin.ignore()` is similiar to `system("PAUSE");` but platform independent